# How can I add a custom attribute to an existing spree model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, spree

New to spree and I wanted to customize the address form during the checkout flow. I added a custom attribute town through a migration to the address model in spree. Also inserted the following code in the initializers/spree.rb`Spree::PermittedAttributes.address_attributes << :town`
also added the following code in models/spree/address_decorator.rb

```
Spree::Address.class_eval do
  attr_accessor :town
  validates_presence_of :town
end
```

Here is where the problem comes in. After filling out the billing address form (the shipping address has use billing address checked by default), I get the validation error that 'Ship address town can't be blank'....if i decide to enter he shipping address manually i notice the town field is still empty and wasn't picked automatically. I can only see one address model in the spree/core/models which i presume is the one used by both the shipping address and the billing address forms. What is it that I am not doing right now that i have to fill the town field manually in the shipping address

Comment: Adding something as an attr_accessor will only allow the value to be populated on that instance of the object, it won't be persisted to the database. You should add the column to the DB in a migration, and remove the `attr_accessor :town`.

Comment: I already added the migration...the billing address form is okay but the shipping address form doesn't pick the town automatically. The user has to enter the town manually in the shipping address. That means unchecking the 'use billing address' in the shipping address form so that one can enter the town. Cant figure out whats wrong with the migartion

Comment: Try to change in your model this `attr_accessor :town` to `attr_accessible :town`